# search element in stl containers

Tags: c++, boost, stl

So I was looking for a way to search a string in a list of strings. I have coded the following

```
bool contains(const std::list<std::string>& data, const std::string& str)
{
        std::list<std::string>::iterator i;
        for(i=data.begin(); i!=data.end(); ++i)
        {   
                if (str == *i) 
                        return true;
        }   

        return false;

}
```

This is just a very basic code. I m aware of the [find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/)  method but it takes in the start and end . Ideal solution would be taking entire container. There are some boost methods for the same , however I m not sure how to use them. can you give some example for boost find for generic searching of element.

Comment: A small recommendation, as of now when calling your function the parameters are _copied_, which can be bad if your list is long. Use (const) references instead: `bool contains(const std::list<std::string> &data, const std::string &str)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference.html):

```
#include <boost/range/algorithm/find.hpp>

auto i = boost::find(container, value);
if (i != boost::end(container))
  doSomething(*i);
```

Comment: i = boost::find(data, value);
        if(*i == value)
                cout<< "value present";
        else
                cout<< "value not present";
useful for checking value

Comment: No, you must ensure that i != boost::end(container), before you dereference i.

Comment: auto i = boost::find(adresses, adress);
if(i != boost::end(adresses) && (*i)!= adress){ .... }

On compiling I get these errros : CoverDownloader.h:135:39: error: no match for ‘operator*’ in ‘*i’
Any ideas why the are coming ?

Comment: First of all, the condition is meaningless, because find() can return either an iterator to "adress" or end iterator. Ensure that your compiler supports C++0x "auto", otherwise define the iterator type explicitly.

Answer (score 4):

`std::find` can takes in the start and end iterators, which basically determine the whole container:

```
std::find(data.begin(), data.end(), str);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not using something along the lines of this :

```
template <typename container, typename T>
bool contains(container& container, T& elt)
{
   return (std::find(container.begin(), container.end, elt) != container.end();
}
```

Comment: You got the argument order wrong, should be `std::find(container.begin(), container.end, elt)`

Comment: I think this is basically a correct answer, so +1. But looking at the end of the question, it may be that the real question here is "how do I call `boost::find`?"

Comment: `container` should be passed by constant reference (and `elt` too, if efficiency is a concern).